# node.js, mongoose and mongodb a pain to install :(

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I'm having trouble getting these 3 packages to install and work together.  Here are the steps I took:

1. Installed nodejs 0.6.3 based on the instructions here for Linux (I downloaded the tar ball from the site as opposed to using the distro in git): https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation
2. Installed npm using the onliner install found here: http://npmjs.org/
3. Installed npm packages for mongodb, mongojs and mongoose.  All seem to install as expected.
4. Created a small program to test and get the following exception:

   ```
   Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/bson'
   at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
   at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
   at require (module.js:368:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/local/mnt/apps/node-v0.6.3/app.js:6:16)
   at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
   at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
   at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
   ```

bson.js appears under this directory for me: /opt/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/bson

I've tried adjusting this line of code to match that and still no success:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose,
ObjectID = require('mongodb/bson').ObjectID;
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?  Just to clarify, do I need to build each npm install I downloaded or does npm do that?

TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mongodb\bson` is no module, where did you get this example from?

Normal use of mongo in node.js is achieved by:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
```

Now you can connect via

```
mongoose.connect("url");
```

When trying to retrieve the `ObjectID` function you shouldn't rely on `mongodb` but on `mongoose` via:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema,
    objectId = schema.ObjectId;
```

Please read the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/).

Comment: I got the sample here: http://webdribble.blogspot.com/2010/07/extdirect-gridpanel-w-connect-on-nodejs.html from 7/2010.  I'm really looking for a simple example of connecting ExtJS to MongoDB with node.

Comment: I went ahead and installed this on my Mac with no issues...it's working as expected now.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible that you installed mongodb in the wrong directory for your project.  One good way to avoid these sorts of issues is to use a package.json file.

Create a directory for your node project and move your .js file into it.  Add a file called package.json with these contents:

```
{  
   "name": "application-name",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
      "mongodb": ">=0.9.6-7",
      "mongoose": ">=0.0.1"
    }
}
```

You can follow the pattern to add your other dependencies as necessary.

Then from that directory, run 'npm install'.  It will install all dependencies for your app.  From there your app should run fine.

Comment: Thank you...I tried your suggestion but get this based on the versions I'm using: npm ERR! Couldn't read dependencies.
npm ERR! Error: 'version' field missing
npm ERR! 'version' Must be X.Y.Z, with an optional trailing tag.
npm ERR! See the section on 'version' in `npm help json`
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/read-json.js:335:13

Comment: @occasl please read standards on package.json. Some fields are mandatory to be present.